# raycast not responding past a certain angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

I have made a game using the unity asset First Person Controller to allow player movement and for them to look around. I have put a cross hair in where a ray cast shoots through and instantiates a bullet. There are no problems with the bullet fire above a certain angle. The bullets follow the cross hair and shoot right in the center but if I look down too far then they no longer shoot where the cross hair is and instead just shoot straight out of the camera.

I think that the capsule that the first person controller makes may be the problem as I cannot find anything in my code.

**LINK TO VIDEO: https://youtu.be/zf2EuL7e_i4**

**Bullet Listener.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletListener : MonoBehaviour {
public Camera mainCamera;
public BulletContoller bulletPrefab;
public GameObject cursor;
private Vector3 cursorPosition;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

        cursorPosition = cursor.transform.position;

        //create ray from camera to mousePosition
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay (cursorPosition);

        //Create bullet from the prefab
        BulletContoller newBullet = Instantiate (bulletPrefab.gameObject).GetComponent<BulletContoller> ();

        //Make the new bullet start at camera
        newBullet.transform.position = mainCamera.transform.position;

        //set bullet direction
        newBullet.SetDirection (ray.direction);

        //Create Bullet Sound
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        audio.Play ();
    }
}
}
```

**Bullet Controller.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletContoller : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody rb;
public float bulletForce;
bool firstTime = false;
Vector3 direction;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}


public void SetDirection (Vector3 dir) {
    direction = dir;
    firstTime = true;
}

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
    //code for when bullet hits something
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Target") {
        this.gameObject.name = "Hit";
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    if (firstTime) {
        rb.AddForce (direction * bulletForce);
        firstTime = false;
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: I would suspect your cursorposition being at fault. Did you verify it is correct?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be right, it can be the capsule from the controller the problem, do this:

1. Create 2 layers named **Player** and **Bullets**.
2. Place the PlayerController in the layer **Player**.
3. Place the Bullet in the layer **Bullets**.
4. Go to **Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics** and in the **Layer Collision Matrix** make sure the **Player** layer and the **Bullets** layer don't collide with each other.

Comment: Works now. Thanks for the help. Didn't know about that before